# How to switch views in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to create an add-in for Microsoft Outlook. I'm at the beginning part of writing the add-in, and what I'd like to have happen is when the user clicks the button I've made, the view switches from whatever they're looking at (either the inbox, calendar, tasks, etc.) to their contacts list.

After much trial and error, this was as far as I got. But I know i'm a ways away.

```
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing
myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Display()
```

Comment: Hi - not sure what your question is?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make a button that switches from whatever view the user is currently looking at, to switch to the contacts view in MS Outlook using an Add-In on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` property to the folder in question (e.g. the folder returned by `GetDefaultFolder`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

```
Dim contactsFolder as Outlook.Folder = Nothing
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing

myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
contactsFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)

Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = contactsFolder
```

The `CurrentFolder` property sets a `Folder` object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How can I do this in vb.net? As Set isn't usable.

Comment: there is no need to use `set` in vb.net

Comment: Hi and thank you again! I need to set each variable to an object reference, as I get this error message when trying to do this: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". I've tried setting each variable to be a member of the class that I'm using, but no dice. Thank you again!

Comment: These two lines: `myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`. And `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = contactsFolder`

Comment: I figured this out. The `application` part needed to be set an object. Thank you again for all your help Eugene.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with your project!